# javascript - change every three items in a step of 6 iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I have an array of items (length could be different). I need to differently change every first three items, then fourth and fifth, then sixth and start again..

For example:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10];
var newArr = arr.map(function (value, index) {
    // indexes 1,2,3 value+1
    // indexes 4,5   value+2
    // index  6     value+3
    // indexes 7,8,9 value+1
    // indexes 10,11 value+2
    // starting over and over...
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant indexes instead of values. If this is the case, then this should work:

```js
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10];
    var newArr = arr.map(function(value, index) {
      var m = index % 6;
      if (m < 3) {
        return value + 1;
      }
      if (m < 5) {
        return value + 2;
      } else {
        return value + 3;
      }
    });
    alert(newArr);
```

Comment: thanks, your solution is the best, readable and very easy to understand!

Answer (score 3):

You can use modulus and some conditions to return what you want

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10];

var newArr = arr.map(function (value, index) {
    var modulo =  (index % 6) + 1,
        added  = 1;
    
    if ( modulo === 4 || modulo === 5 ) added = 2;
    if ( modulo === 6 ) added = 3;
    
    return value + added;
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArr, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Golfed, just for fun

```
var newArr = arr.map(function (v, i) {
    return v + ([3,4].indexOf(i%6) != -1 ? 2 : (i%6) === 5 ? 3 : 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10];
func_123 = function( value, index ){
 console.log( 'stuff of first three ' + value + ' ' + index )};
func_45 = function( value, index ){
 console.log( 'stuff of four & five ' + value + ' ' + index )};
func_6 = function( value, index ){
 console.log( 'stuff of six ' + value + ' ' + index )};

var newArr = arr.map(function (value, index) {
[ func_123, func_123, func_123, func_45, func_45, func_6 ][ index % 6 ]( value, index )});
```